# Why are some lines white in my sublime text editor?

Tags: json, sublimetext3

I'm looking at a JSON file in Sublime Text 3.

Almost all the lines of the file are yellow, except some that are white. Why are they white?

Here's what I mean:

[image]

Comment: How long is the line that's white?

Comment: It's 246663 columns long according to sublime text 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a hard limit of **16,384** characters for each line; longer lines are not highlighted. The developers of Sublime were afraid this would otherwise take too long, making editing less responsive. After all, the entire file needs to be re-analysed upon each edit (or at least the part from the active line onward).

[Source.](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/513)